# The limit of Nakagami pdf.

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

Show that when $m\rightarrow\infty$, the probability density function (pdf) of Nakagami distribution
$$f(x;\,m,\Omega) = \frac{2m^m}{\Gamma(m)\Omega^m}x^{2m-1}\exp\left(-\frac{m}{\Omega}x^2\right)$$
becomes an impulse function.

Comment: What is an impulse function?

Comment: @IgorRivin The impulse function here is defined as the Dirac delta function $\delta(x-\sqrt{\Omega})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Stirling approximation of the Gamma function. This will reduce the first fraction to something like $(e/\Omega)^m,$ and multiplying with the $x$ term something like $$\frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{e x^2}{\Omega}\right)^m.$$ Now multiply by the exponential, to get something like
$$\frac1x \left(\frac{e x^2}{\Omega \exp(x^2/\Omega)}\right)^m.$$ The thing being raised to the $m$-th power should be smaller than $1$ (you should check) always, and the integral is $1$ (since it is always a PDF...) In fact, the thing raised to the $m$th power is one when $x^2=\Omega$ and only then.